# Counting records in MySQL with a complicated HAVING Statement

Tags: mysql, having

I have a query which returns map markers within a radius (in miles) of a given position (lat/lng). My query works when reading the data, but I am wanting to set up pagination so need to count the records first to determine how many pages of data I will have.

My query is :

```
SET @LAT := 53.068464;
SET @LNG := -4.076113;
SET @Miles := 10;


SELECT (3959 * acos( cos( radians(@LAT) ) * cos( radians( M.Lat ) ) * cos( 
radians( M.Lng ) - radians(@LNG) ) + sin( radians(@LAT) ) * sin( radians( 
M.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, M.MarkerId, M.Title 
FROM Markers AS M 
HAVING distance < @Miles
ORDER BY M.DateStamp desc, Distance
```

I have tried

```
SELECT COUNT(MarkerId) 
FROM Markers
HAVING (3959 * acos( cos( radians(@LAT) ) * cos( radians( Lat ) ) * cos( 
radians( Lng ) - radians(@LNG) ) + sin( radians(@LAT) ) * sin( radians( Lat ) 
) ) ) < @Miles
```

but it fails trying to reference the Lat and Lng fields from the Markers table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods.  One is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT (3959 * acos( cos( radians(@LAT) ) * cos( radians( M.Lat ) ) * cos( 
    radians( M.Lng ) - radians(@LNG) ) + sin( radians(@LAT) ) * sin( radians( 
    M.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, M.MarkerId, M.Title 
      FROM Markers AS M 
      HAVING distance < @Miles
    ) x
```

The second method is to use [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) and then the `FOUND_ROWS()` function:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (3959 * acos( cos( radians(@LAT) ) * cos( radians( M.Lat ) ) * cos( 
radians( M.Lng ) - radians(@LNG) ) + sin( radians(@LAT) ) * sin( radians( 
M.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, M.MarkerId, M.Title 
FROM Markers AS M 
HAVING distance < @Miles
ORDER BY M.DateStamp desc, Distance ;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str1="select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (3959 * acos( cos( radians(@LAT) ) * cos( radians( M.Lat ) ) * cos( 
radians( M.Lng ) - radians(@LNG) ) + sin( radians(@LAT) ) * sin( radians( 
M.Lat ) ) ) ) AS distance, M.MarkerId, M.Title 
FROM Markers AS M 
HAVING distance < @Miles
ORDER BY M.DateStamp desc, Distance limit ".$offset.",".$limit;
$q1 = mysql_query($str1);
$result=array();
$str2="SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS Count";
$q2 = mysql_query($str2);
while($objCount= $q2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result["TotalRows"] = $objCount['Count'];
 }
if ($q1->num_rows > 0) {       
            $result["Rows"] = mysql_result($q1);
} else {
            $result["Rows"] = array();
}       
return $result;
```